# why Syntax errors shown in pipenv environment after executing the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, pipenv

I was run this module  via python3 `pipenv` and it works but after I closed the Jupiter and I try again to open the Jupiter and run the same code I got this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be single line.

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
```